# Primefaces - Dialog fields are empty but not all of them

Tags: primefaces, dialog

my problem is really strange ( to me at least ).
I have a dialog written in Primefaces.
From the beginning I had the problem that the fields have not been shown, I had to mark them so that I could read the content.
Then I wrote a css styleclass: color black in order to have it shown. This really worked ( for IE and Chrome ). Afterwards, I had to enlarge the columns from 2 to 4 because the dialog became unreadable. Now, the same thing happens again, I cannot read all the fields, here is a screenshot. Maybe, someone knows what I am missing here? Thank you very much.

[image: dialog_error]

Here is the code:

```
                <h:form id="form">
                <p:dialog header="Transaction Detail" widgetVar="transactionDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                    <p:outputPanel id="transactionDetail" style="text-align:left;">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="4" rendered="#{not empty transactionBacking.selectedTransaction}" columnClasses="label,value">
                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Transaction Id" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{transactionBacking.selectedTransaction.tableTransactionId}"/>

                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputText"  value="Customer - customerId" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{transactionBacking.selectedTransaction.customer.customerId}"/>

                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
            </ui:define>
```

Comment: Your problem to us is even stranger since all we have is an image and you also have code... [mcve] please

Comment: You are right, sorry for not having posted it - I edited it.

Comment: Did you try to remove some code from your Dialog, in other word make it simple ?!?

Comment: Heck, even remove the dialog, remove the outputPanel, grid,  the styles etc..

Comment: Hi, yes I already tried that but it did not change anything. What I did now was to get rid of the styleClass ( it was a workaround some days ago because of this it was working ). And therefore I wrote style="color: black;" and it is working now. Strangely, the left side is in full black, the right sight still in "normal" black, but it is working. I think there are some problems with the css` we are using.

Comment: This last comment of yours is strange. I said to remove the styles, you said you tried and it did not solve it but changing the style did. Then you did not remove all styles. And your answer is not a workaround, it is what you normally do in creating a [mcve]. See my comment on the answer too

Comment: Use css inspector in firebug to see what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround. I wrote

```
style="color: black"
```

instead of

```
styleclass="outputText"
```

I think there are some problems with our CSS´ but I have to investigate that much more.

Comment: This is kind of useless for others in the context of the question since it is not clear on what outputText in styleClass does and what the other possible styles do with regard to 'specificity'. Your question is not a [mcve] so please improve that, remove this answer and when you find the real cause, post that as an answer